# Tab title is not displayed if it is in the second component (Angular)

Tags: angular, tabs

I am using material css framework in conjunction with Angular (both latest versions). When I create tabs in one component everything works fine. When I make each tab as a separate component, then the tab titles stop working (the tab functionality itself and its content still work fine.). Below is the code:

This is how a single component template looks like (when everything works well):

```
<mat-tab-group mat-align-tabs="start">
   <mat-tab *ngFor="let colors_hue of globalService.colors_hues; let i = index">
     <ng-template mat-tab-label>
       test
     </ng-template>
     test2
   </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

[It looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kUlB.png)

And here is the code when I use 2 components (and when tab headers don't work):

```
<mat-tab-group mat-align-tabs="start">
  <mat-tab *ngFor="let colors_hue of globalService.colors_hues; let i = index">
    <app-hue>
    </app-hue>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

app-hue component:

```
<ng-template mat-tab-label>
  test
</ng-template>
test2
```

[This is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ye4nX.png)

Here's my question: why is this happening and how to fix this problem?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: When you encapsulate the ```ng-template``` inside app-hue, you add "a layer" inbetween the ```mat-tab``` and the ```mat-tab-label```, you can inspect your HTML to better understand this

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to find a solution to this problem, but I got around the problem with this: I left the headers in the main component and pasted the tab content into a separate tab component.
Main component code:

```
    <mat-tab-group mat-align-tabs="start">
      <mat-tab *ngFor="let colors_hue of globalService.colors_hues; let i = index">
        <ng-template mat-tab-label>
         test
        </ng-template>
        <app-hue>
        </app-hue>
      </mat-tab>
    </mat-tab-group>
```

Tab component code (app-hue):

```
test2
```

This was enough for everything to work as I intended. Therefore, I did not seek further the answer to my question. However, it is still interesting why this is happening. So if someone did come across this, do not hesitate to answer.

As for maury844's comment, yes, thanks, and it was clear from the start that Angular generates additional code (layer). But in one component, he also generates it and everything works.